# Spyder on Windows crashes when entering "help("modules")"

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, access-violation, spyder

So, it seems my computer's python (Both python 2 and 3) configuration is screwed up in some clandestine way. Originally, I uninstalled Enthought Canopy (Windows 10 64 bit) using "Apps & Features" instead of "Uninstall a Program". Once running spyder through Anaconda I ran "help("modules")" in the ipython window and received the following error:

```
C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__init__.py:13:
ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated. You should
import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
"You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
```

Followed by several similar errors for different files, seemingly random.

After these errors seem to overwhelm the system it erases the previous log and replaces it with a red box titled: "An error occurred while starting the kernel"

```
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x00002850 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\parentpoller.py",
        line 94 in run
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00000f5c (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 295 in wait
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 551 in wait
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py",
        line 834 in run
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py",
        line 60 in needs_sqlite
    File "", line 2 in run
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000026c8 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\heartbeat.py",
        line 61 in run
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00001fe0 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\poll.py",
        line 99 in poll
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py",
        line 122 in poll
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\ioloop.py",
        line 862 in start
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py",
        line 177 in start
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\iostream.py",
        line 72 in _thread_main
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864 in run
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00000458 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py",
        line 209 in load_font
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\qtawesome\iconic_font.py",
        line 178 in __init__
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\qtawesome\__init__.py",
        line 36 in _instance
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\qtawesome\__init__.py",
        line 153 in load_font
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\icon_manager.py",
        line 258 in icon
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\runconfig.py",
        line 457 in RunConfigPage
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\runconfig.py",
        line 452 in
    File "", line 205 in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "", line 678 in exec_module
    File "", line 655 in _load_unlocked
    File "", line 950 in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "", line 961 in _find_and_load
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_profiler\profiler.py",
        line 22 in
    File "", line 205 in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "", line 678 in exec_module
    File "", line 655 in _load_unlocked
    File "", line 950 in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "", line 961 in _find_and_load
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_profiler\__init__.py",
        line 6 in
    File "", line 205 in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "", line 678 in exec_module
    File "", line 655 in _load_unlocked
    File "", line 950 in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "", line 961 in _find_and_load
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\pkgutil.py", line 92 in walk_packages
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\pydoc.py", line 2079 in run
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\pydoc.py", line 2050 in listmodules
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\pydoc.py", line 1899 in help
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\pydoc.py", line 1858 in __call__
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\_sitebuiltins.py", line 103 in __call__
    File "", line 1 in
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
        line 2881 in run_code
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
        line 2827 in run_ast_nodes
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
        line 2717 in run_cell
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py",
        line 501 in run_cell
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py",
        line 196 in do_execute
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
        line 390 in execute_request
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
        line 228 in dispatch_shell
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
        line 276 in dispatcher
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
        line 275 in null_wrapper
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
        line 414 in _run_callback
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
        line 472 in _handle_recv
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py",
        line 440 in _handle_events
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
        line 275 in null_wrapper
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\tornado\ioloop.py",
        line 887 in start
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py",
        line 177 in start
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py",
        line 474 in start
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py",
        line 223 in main
    File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py",
        line 227 in
```

I've tried:

```
spyder --reset
```

As well as uninstalling every version of python on my computer, along with every directory folder and file I could find. After reinstallation, the same problem occurs.

My current sys.path is:

```
['',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\spyder\\utils\\site',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\Lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\Lib',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.1-py3.6.egg',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
'C:\\Users\\Jacob\\.ipython']
```

I haven't been able to find this specific error anywhere I've looked on the web, so hopefully someone here has a clue where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the issue reported at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4014 . In that case, the solution is to upgrade qtawesome (a dependency of spyder) to version 0.4.4 or higher. If you installed using Anaconda, the command is: `conda upgrade qtawesome`.